# How to print multiple line from variable in BASH to HTML output

Tags: html, bash

I am having a problem executing a script that basically capture the disk space from the server and output the result to an html page.

STORAGE=$(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n)

The output in STDOUT is OK. It is well formatted. When I echo the variable to a HTML page, the output becomes one line, just like this one:

/dev/vx/dsk/localdg/wm7x01 vxfs 30G 21G 9.3G 70% /apps/wm7x01 /dev/mapper/vg00-vrts ext3 6.9G 4.7G 2.3G 68% /vrts_install /dev/mapper/vg00-ora11g_cli ext3 7.7G 4.1G 3.3G 57% /usr/oracle11g_cli /dev/mapper/vg00-repackage ext3 1008M 423M 586M 42% /var/spool/repackage /dev/vx/dsk/cfs_dcgnts_dg/shared vxfs 220G 91G 130G 42% /apps/shared

I even tried using the quotations: echo "$STORAGE"

I also tried using array: echo "{STORAGE[@]}"

Unfortunately, all yields the same result. Can you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick, ugly hack:

```
STORAGE=$(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n | sed 's:$:<br/>:')
```

This puts a line break at the end of every line ... but it won't format it as a table.  For that, here's another quick, ugly hack:

```
STORAGE="<table>$(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n | sed 's:$:<br/>:;s:  *:</td><td>:;s:.*:<tr><td>&</td></tr>:')</table>"
```

This replaces all occurrances of one or more spaces with the necessary HTML to split columns, then adds table row wrappers to each line, and finally wraps the whole output in HTML `<table>` tags.

I say again: *this is an ugly hack*.  It should work most of the time in a pinch, but will definitely break if you have anything else adding spaces, like a device name or filesystem name.  (Ever mounted a USB stick with a space in its volume?)

Note that this ugly hack does not use anything specific to bash.  You could do it just as easily in more traditional Bourne-style shells.

Another possibility, perhaps easier, would be simply to mark this text as being preformatted (which it is):

```
STORAGE="<pre>$(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n)</pre>"
```

Finally, if you want to get all bashy with this and use arrays, here's an example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

mapfile -t a_storage < <(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n)

td="th"
echo -n "<table>"
for line in "${a_storage[@]}"; do
  a_line=($line)
  echo "<tr>"
  for field in ${a_line[@]}; do
    echo "    <$td> ${field//</&lt;} </$td>"
  done
  echo -n "  </tr>"
  td="td"
done
echo "</table>"
```

This does pretty much exactly the same as the one-liners above, but it spells things out for you.  It is still susceptible to unexpected whitespace.

Bash is not an ideal programming environment for generating HTML.

Comment: Thanks Ghoti, this suits my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to learn about HTML a bit and how to format text into tables and columns?

Anyway, place `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags before and after your content like so:

```
echo "<pre>$STORAGE</pre>"
```

It won't create an HTML table but at least you won't lose your whitespace